# BASH translating FASTA file's DNA to protein. Possible to insert awk array?

Tags: linux, bash, shell, awk, sed

I am super new at coding and have been trying to insert an awk array/command? into a bash script to translate DNA to protein and output the protein frequencies to a file. In my endless searching after numerous failures the past several days, I have seen many others asking this, but I cannot seem to put the pieces together from their answers.

I should probably note that this must be in BASH. This is for a class and is only part of the assignment. I am not trying to come across as asking someone to do my homework. I am honestly am completely out of ideas and really need help.

If someone could at least explain how you go from an command line awk [eg: awk -f commandtodo.awk filetoread.txt ] to putting this in a BASH script, I would greatly appriciate it.

If someone has additional time to explain this to me like I'm five here are the pieces I am trying to put together:

Here's the awk array/command I am trying to use:

```
# translates DNA to protein
#this one works on command line
BEGIN{c["ATA"]="I"; c["ATC"]="I"; c["ATT"]="I"; c["ATG"]="M";
    c["ACA"]="T"; c["ACC"]="T"; c["ACG"]="T"; c["ACT"]="T";
    c["AAC"]="N"; c["AAT"]="N"; c["AAA"]="K"; c["AAG"]="K";
    c["AGC"]="S"; c["AGT"]="S"; c["AGA"]="R"; c["AGG"]="R";
    c["CTA"]="L"; c["CTC"]="L"; c["CTG"]="L"; c["CTT"]="L";
    c["CCA"]="P"; c["CCC"]="P"; c["CCG"]="P"; c["CCT"]="P";
    c["CAC"]="H"; c["CAT"]="H"; c["CAA"]="Q"; c["CAG"]="Q";
    c["CGA"]="R"; c["CGC"]="R"; c["CGG"]="R"; c["CGT"]="R";
    c["GTA"]="V"; c["GTC"]="V"; c["GTG"]="V"; c["GTT"]="V";
    c["GCA"]="A"; c["GCC"]="A"; c["GCG"]="A"; c["GCT"]="A";
    c["GAC"]="D"; c["GAT"]="D"; c["GAA"]="E"; c["GAG"]="E";
    c["GGA"]="G"; c["GGC"]="G"; c["GGG"]="G"; c["GGT"]="G";
    c["TCA"]="S"; c["TCC"]="S"; c["TCG"]="S"; c["TCT"]="S";
    c["TTC"]="F"; c["TTT"]="F"; c["TTA"]="L"; c["TTG"]="L";
    c["TAC"]="Y"; c["TAT"]="Y"; c["TAA"]="_"; c["TAG"]="_";
    c["TGC"]="C"; c["TGT"]="C"; c["TGA"]="_"; c["TGG"]="W"}
{i=1; p=""}
{do {
  s=substr($0, i, 3)
  printf ("%s ", s)
  {if (c[s]==""){p=p"    "} else {p=p c[s]" "}}
  i=i+3}
while (s!="")}
{printf("\n%s\n", p)}
```

Here's the BASH loop I am trying to insert this into. This is the basic frame I was given.

```
#!/bin/bash

if [ "$#" -lt 1 ]                                      ## checking if there is an input file
then
    echo "no input file ..."
else
    myFile=$1                                       ## myFile = input file 
    echo "input file name=" $myFile
    numSeq=$(cat $myFile | grep "^>" | wc -l)      ## getting the number of sequences
    cat $myFile | tr -d [:space:] > DNAfile2.txt    ## edit the space out of the sequences
    if [ $numSeq -gt 0 ]
    then
        echo there are $numSeq sequences in $myFile"." These are":"
        nameSeq=$(cat $myFile | grep -o -E "^>\w+")
        awk 'BEGIN{RS=">"}{print $1}' < DNAfile2.txt | grep "Header_" > DNAfile3.txt
        for i in $nameSeq                  ## for loop to collect sequence data for translation 
        do
            seqHeader=$(echo $i | tr -d ">")
            echo $seqHeader

            sequenceFile=$(cat DNAfile3.txt | grep $seqHeader | sed -e "s/$seqHeader/>/" | cut -d ">" -f2)
            echo $sequenceFile
            ############
            ## your work happens here
            ############    
        done
    else
        echo "there are no sequence in" $myFile
    fi
fi
```

Any help would be greatly appriciated. Thanks

Comment: It would also be helpful if you could narrow down the part of your script where errors occur. Also you have so many extra spaces in your script, it makes it more difficult to read.

Comment: The scripts (as/is) independently work. When I go to try to insert the awk array (which I am most likely doing incorrectly) the problems start to arise. Do you have a suggestion on how to put these together? Thanks for your response.

Comment: I'm no awk expert by any means. See what happens when you insert the awk array in your script on http://shellcheck.net. Many problems can be solved by that alone.

Comment: just add the same command you're using at CLI to the script.  I'm guessing the input file for your command will be $sequenceFile.

Comment: How you go from an command line awk [eg of what I type: awk -f dnatrans.awk fastafile.txt ] to one in a bash script? That's the main issue I'm having

Comment: I would do this in a higher level language such as Python.

Comment: I would too since it looks much easier IMO, but I'm not allowed to use anything but BASH.

Comment: "If someone could at least explain how you go from an command line awk  ... to putting in a Bash script". Sure, easy enough. `echo $seqFile; awk 'BEGIN{....} { ....}' file` You just paste in your code between `'` (single quotes). If your code includes single quotes, then you have to work around that. there are several techniques. (I don't see any singleQs in your code). Not sure where these 'code-snippet' things come from, please use the `{}` format tool at the top left of the edit box on highlighted text to format as code/data/output. Good luck.

Comment: AND, shells have a maximum size for a "word" that can be between `'` chars, so if you keep expanding your code, you'll come to a point where you get mysterious error messages. Look for info on shell `Here-Documents`, those are unlimited in size. i.e. `awk <<EOS {your code} EOS` (closing EOS has to be only thing on closing line).  If you search here for `[bash] EOS` or [bash] EOF` you'll find many examples. Good luck.

Comment: Very helpful. Thanks.